# Wireguard "Unknown device type" "Protocol not supported"

Tags: kernel, vpn, systemd, wireguard

I recently installed Raspberry Pi OS on my Pi 3b.  After some basic configuration and running `raspi-config`, I installed wireguard using apt and the debian backport repos, according to [a tutorial](https://engineerworkshop.com/blog/how-to-set-up-wireguard-on-a-raspberry-pi#install-wireguard-on-the-raspberry-pi).

I wasn't able to start the service though:

```
# systemctl start wg-quick@wg0
Job for wg-quick@wg0.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status wg-quick@wg0.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

# journalctl -u wg-quick@wg0
raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
raspberrypi wg-quick[1773]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
raspberrypi wg-quick[1773]: Error: Unknown device type.
raspberrypi wg-quick[1773]: Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported
raspberrypi wg-quick[1773]: [#] ip link delete dev wg0
raspberrypi wg-quick[1773]: Cannot find device "wg0"
raspberrypi systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
raspberrypi systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

The key lines are `Unknown device type` and `Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported`.  It seems like wireguard isn't able to create a new wireguard interface, as if the kernel module didn't exist...

Answer (score 6):

According to [a comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/elfato/rpi4_unable_to_access_interface_protocol_not/fdq6rs5?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) on r/Wireguard, this error is caused by having the wrong kernel headers:

> dkms packages (wireguard-dkms this time) need kernel headers for
> current kernel you have loaded (uname -a). As long as kernel is
> updated through apt or aptitude you should not run into problems, but
> if you update kernel with rpi-update you'll likely get newer kernel
> than what is available through package repository and there will be no
> headers available for it

The Foundation now offers headers for the rpi kernel, they just have to be installed.  From the official online documentation on [kernel headers](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/headers.md):

> If you are compiling a kernel module or similar, you will need the
> Linux Kernel headers. These provide the various function and structure
> definitions required when compiling code that interfaces with the
> kernel.
>
> ```
> sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
> ```
>
> Note that it can take quite a while for this command to complete, as
> it installs a lot of small files. There is no progress indicator.

After installing `raspberrypi-kernel-headers`, and rebooting, Wireguard started normally.

Comment: The kernel and kernel header packages were updated yesterday. So start with `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade -y; sudo reboot`.

Comment: @Dougie So my answer might already have been obsolete by a day, SMH.  Oh well, so long as the correct information is out there.  You might want to put the `dist-upgrade` command in an answer so people can see and upvote it if it works.  I probably won't pick a best answer because I already fixed it for me and won't be testing the `dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't followed the tutorial you used but wireguard is heavy under development and there are some outdated installation tutorials on the web. Try this [Wireguard installation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109521/79866) that uses an [official backport from Debian Bullseye](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=wireguard&searchon=names&section=all&suite=buster-backports). I have just tested it again with success.

Answer (score 1):

For those that have the same issue but had a working wireguard set-up, (Linux headers were installed in the past) a bad kernel update may provoke a Linux headers mismatch.

I tried the following command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure raspberrypi-kernel-headers`

and that solved my issue.

Comment: I had a working setup, and dpkg-reconfigure command failed with an error. After using the buster backports repo (as suggested by Ingo's answer), everything worked again

Answer (score 0):

On recent distributions there is no tinkering with the headers necessary. However, the Pi needs a reboot after installing `wireguard`.